# If both f and g are differentiable at a, find the limits $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{xf(a)−af(x)}{x−a}$ and $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)g(a)−f(a)g(x)}{x−a}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at a, find:

1. $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{xf(a)−af(x)}{x−a}$$
2. $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)g(a)−f(a)g(x)}{x−a}$$

I know for the first one that I need to somehow reduce it into a form of $$f'(a) =\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)−af(a)}{x−a}$$ and I get as far as:
$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{xf(a)−af(x)}{x−a} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{(-a)f(x)−(-x)f(a)}{x−a}$$
how do I pull the $-a$ and $-x$ out to get an answer based on $f'(a)$?

Comment: How to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference): to get $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{xf(a)-af(x)}{x-a}$$ type `$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{xf(a)-af(x)}{x-a}$`.

Comment: For the first one, try adding and subtracting $xf(x)$ to the numerator.

Comment: You should typeset your question using (MathJax)[http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference] and tell us what you have done to solve this yoursef.

Comment: Sorry, question edited.

Comment: @Bungo Can you illustrate? I don't see how that helps

Comment: @leaf $$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to a}\frac{xf(a) - af(x)}{x-a} &= \lim_{x \to a}\frac{xf(a) - xf(x)}{x-a} + \lim_{x \to a}\frac{xf(x) - af(x)}{x-a}\\ &= \lim_{x \to a} x\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(a)-f(x)}{x-a}+\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \\ &= a(-f'(a)) + f(a)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: How did you go from $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{xf(x)-af(x)}{x-a}$ to $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$? @Bungo

Comment: @Leaf $$\frac{xf(x) - af(x)}{x-a} = f(x)\frac{x-a}{x-a} = f(x)$$

Comment: Any hints on the second one? I've been trying with no success @Bungo

Comment: @Leaf Did you try adding and subtracting $f(x)g(x)$ to the numerator and manipulating similarly to the first problem?

Comment: Got it, thanks! f(a)(-g'(a))+g(a)f'(a)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Notice that
$$xf(a)-af(x) = (xf(a)-af(a)) - (af(x)-af(a))$$
so you can relate the first limit to the derivatives of the functions $x \mapsto xf(a)$ and $x \mapsto af(x)$.

A similar trick works for the second limit.

Comment: I don't really see how to apply this

Comment: For example,
$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{af(x)-af(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a} \left( a \cdot \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \right) = a \cdot \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = af'(a)$$
using the limit definition of the derivative of a function.